# ¿Que API se puede utilizar para desplegar los movimientos de mi cuenta?

Tags: mercadopago

Somos un partido político que se apoya en las tecnologías de la información y comunicación y nuestro método de donaciones utiliza MercadoPago.

Como valor fundamental promovemos la transparencia y eso aplica a la financiación del partido. Es por esto que necesitamos mostrar todos los movimientos realizados tanto de entrada como de salida con la información del usuario que las efectuó.

Encontré la siguiente API pero no retorna información del usuario más que el user_id. Necesitamos al menos nombre, apellido y correo electrónico.

```
https://api.mercadopago.com/mercadopago_account/movements/search
```

¿Alguna sugerencia? ¿o quizás haya posibilidad de la implementación de una nueva API que sirva el propósito de tener finanzas públicas?

Gracias desde ya.

Comment: Hola Leo, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en español. Esta comunidad de programadores no se especializa en Mercado Pago, por lo que tendrás que aportar más elementos que permitan ayudarte. Lo primero es que te asegures que tu pregunta cumple con esta guía __[ask]__. En segundo lugar, haz lo posible para incluir un __[mcve]__ Usa los botones de formato que te ofrece el editor y limita el error a la parte más relevante de tu problema. Tal vez te interese consultar esta publicación: [Por qué no somos el soporte al cliente de _Mercado Pago_](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2525/638).

Answer (score -1):

eso es correcto el endpoint /movements/search retorna información únicamente sobre los movimientos identificando al usuario con un id.

Para obtener el detalle de la información de un usuario debes usar otro endpoint /users/

```
https://api.mercadopago.com/users/USER_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

El cual te retornara información sobre el usuario consultado, solo información publica.